# Able to connect to database via Oracle SQL Developer but fails to connect via Load Runner

Tags: loadrunner, vugen

Via Oracle SQL Developer as well as JMeter, able to connect Database.

But, when we try to connect DB via load runner(Vugen), getting below error:

**Replay Error From Vugen:**

> "DB Connection failed {"A network-related or instance-specific error
> occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was
> not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is
> correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
> (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
> connection to SQL Server)"}"

**LR code used to connect DB:**

```
lr_db_connect("StepName=DatabaseConnection", 
    "ConnectionString=Data Source=XXXXXX;Initial Catalog=InvDatabase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XXXXX;Password=XXXXX", 
    "ConnectionName=XXXXX", 
    "ConnectionType=SQL", 
    LAST );
```

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK, you are connecting via ODBC it looks like.   Your ODBC driver is configured as Named Pipes.   Use ODBC Query from MS Office as a test app tyo see if you can connect across the same ODBC Driver

Comment: I am not sure/clear on the above comment.. Can you suggest any valid solution to fix the error addressed/occurring via load runner when I connect to DB

Comment: I did.  Validate your ODBC driver with a different ODBC client.  IN this case I recommended MSQuery from Microsoft Office, a fairly ubiquitous solution in most enterprises.   You have your ODBC driver configured for a named pipe connection.  That usually works inside of the same host, but across hosts you should be looking at something more routable such as a TCP/IP connection with a FQDN or IP address as the target

Comment: Your error is not coming from LoadRunner.  IT is coming from the ODBC driver and the named pipes interface.   It cannot connect over a named pipe.

Comment: i updated solution. thank you any how :-)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed, once followed below:

Need to update tnsnames.ora file to have DB connection details.

tnsnames.ora file path in oracle installed folder below:  C:\ORACLE\product\19.0.0\client_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora

If you dont have tnsnames.ora file, you can copy the same file from below path, update it to have your DB connection details and place it under admin folder.

C:\ORACLE\product\19.0.0\client_1\network\admin\sample